# Mac OS X "Verify Certificate" every time connecting to secure wireless

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, security, certificate

Every time connecting to the secure wireless, Macs are getting a prompt to verify the certificate:

> ### Verify Certificate
>
> Authenticating to network "Network-Name"
>
> Before authenticating to server "ServerName", you should examine the server's certificate to ensure that it is appropriate for this network.
>
> To view the certificate click 'Show Certificate'.

Screenshot below; some names redacted.

This is happening on multiple Macs, every time they reconnect to the wireless. I thought it was a cert trust issue, but selecting "Always trust" does not have any effect. Also the cert is signed by DigiCert.

This seems to be a problem on OS 10.11, but I haven't confirmed that previous OSes are able to actually trust the cert. Other OSes are not having this problem.

How can I permanently trust this cert so it remembers it next time I connect? What could be causing this?

More info from Network Preferences:

- 802.1X: Default
- Authenticated via EAP-PEAP (MSCHAPv2)
- WPA2 Enterprise
- Network is remembered to automatically join

[image: Mac Verify Certificate prompt]

Comment: After further investigation, it looks like the intermediate cert is not installed, so it's not trusted for some reason.

Comment: @ Yanzzee what did you do to fix this issue?

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at this, but as far as I know we had to install the Digicert intermediate cert into the freeradius server for clients to trust it.

Comment: It does seem that macOS High Sierra has solved this issue, about macOS forgetting that you've trusted certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a user at my work and I was able to resolve the issue by removing the Macbook from our domain, deleting the certificate, and then rejoining the Macbook to the domain. After I did that it just asked to verify the cert once and then it was good.

Comment: On High Sierra (10.13.6), removing the certificate and reconnecting did the trick.